# PATINDEX test for phone number format

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have phone fields in the database like the following:

```
phone_num VARCHAR(50) NULL
```

It looks like just about all of these phone fields are 10 characters or less. If they are 10 characters, I will format them in the form of `(xxx) xxx-xxxx`.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[FormatPhone](@Phone NVARCHAR(50)) RETURNS NVARCHAR(50) AS BEGIN
  declare @fone NVARCHAR(50), @len INT;
  set @fone=LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(@Phone,'')));
  set @len = LEN(@fone);
  return case
    when @len=10 then
        '(' + SUBSTRING(@fone, 1, 3) + ') ' +
         SUBSTRING(@fone, 4, 3) + '-' + 
         SUBSTRING(@fone, 7, 4)
    when 10<@len then
        '(' + SUBSTRING(@fone, 1, 3) + ') ' + 
         SUBSTRING(@fone, 4, 3) + '-' + 
         SUBSTRING(@fone, 7, 4) + 'x' + 
         SUBSTRING(@fone, 11, @len)
    else
        @fone
    end;
END
```

The `@fone` variable eliminates `NULL` values and leading/trailing blank spaces.

Our software only inputs phone numbers using the numeric values.

However, there is nothing to prevent one of the many administrators at any of our customer's sites from manually executing some SQL to insert or update a record.

They could see the format we use, and try manually entering that data.

Or, they could try entering it as `xxx.xxx.xxxx`, or ...???? Who knows?

What is a good way to search my `@fone` variable for any indication that it has already been modified? Is [PATINDEX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx) best?

Comment: you just want to know if you're data is still in this format?  (xxx) xxx-xxxx

Comment: No, but if it is 10 digits, I want to return it in that format. If it is only 7 digits, I will just return `1234567`, `IsBlank`, or whatever our customer decides to use that field for. If there are 10 digits, `NNN.NNN.NNNN`, or `NNN-NNN-NNNN`, I can return `(NNN) NNN-NNNN`. If there are 11 to 15 digits, I can return it in the form `(NNN) NNN-NNNNxNNN` (I had to use N).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gordon's answer would be great if I were allowed to go in and add a constraint.

Since I am not, I ended up by creating the following **FormatPhone** function for our database:

```
-- =============================================
-- Author:      jp2code
-- Create date: 09 June 2016
-- Description: Formats a integer phone number value.
-- =============================================
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[FormatPhone](@Phone NVARCHAR(50)) RETURNS NVARCHAR(50) AS BEGIN
    declare @fone NVARCHAR(50), @len INT;
    set @fone=LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(@Phone,'')));
    set @len = LEN(@fone);
    if ISNUMERIC(@fone + '.0e0')=1 begin
        return case
            when @len=7 then
                SUBSTRING(@fone, 1, 3) + '-' + 
                SUBSTRING(@fone, 4, 4)
            when @len=8 then
                SUBSTRING(@fone, 1, 1) + '-' + 
                SUBSTRING(@fone, 2, 3) + '-' + 
                SUBSTRING(@fone, 5, 4)
            when @len=9 then
                SUBSTRING(@fone, 1, 3) + '-' + 
                SUBSTRING(@fone, 4, 4) + ' x' + 
                SUBSTRING(@fone, 8, 2)
            when @len=10 then
                '(' + SUBSTRING(@fone, 1, 3) + ') ' + 
                SUBSTRING(@fone, 4, 3) + '-' + 
                SUBSTRING(@fone, 7, 4)
            when 10<@len then
                '(' + SUBSTRING(@fone, 1, 3) + ') ' + 
                SUBSTRING(@fone, 4, 3) + '-' + 
                SUBSTRING(@fone, 7, 4) + ' x' + 
                SUBSTRING(@fone, 11, @len)
            else
                @fone
            end;
    end
    return @fone;
END
```

Feel free to use this or modify it as you see fit.

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm, after fixing all the numbers, I think you want a `check` constraint:

```
alter table t
    add constraint chk_t_phone_num
        check (phone_num like '([0-9][0-9][0-9]) [0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]);
```

This will ensure that the values put into the database are correct.

Comment: It's a large company, Gordon, with thousands of clients running this database. Adding a constraint like that would require approval from many different departments, training of the various company admins, etc. I really just want to alter the data returned from a view.